# Taking variables from another class?

Tags: java, swing

I am writing a program in Java (with using Swing) to connect database. I've got two classes. Program started from interface.java, where create form with user interface, where I've got fields for login and password and button for connect. When user press the button, second class (connecting) should started.

And there is my questions - is it possible to taking variables from one class (interface) to another class (connecting.java)? And if it is, then how?

Code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;


public class Interface extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField textField;
    private JTextField textField_1;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    GUI frame = new GUI();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public GUI() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 615, 300);
        setTitle("DefectLoader");
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Login");
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(10, 8, 65, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel);

        JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("Password");
        lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(10, 40, 65, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel_1);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBounds(80, 5, 100, 20);
        contentPane.add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        textField_1 = new JTextField();
        textField_1.setBounds(80, 35, 100, 20);
        contentPane.add(textField_1);
        textField_1.setColumns(10);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Connect");
        btnNewButton.setBounds(10, 85, 170, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnNewButton);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, possible. Can you please show us the code ?

Comment: OK, so now you added half of the code. How does Connecting.java come into play and what variables do you need to pass to it?

Comment: And also, what have you tried and how did it not work?

Comment: I need to send two variables to Connection.java (string type, one for login and one for password).
In Connection.java I've got only:

public class Connect 
{
 public static void method_connect()
 {
  System.out.println("Connected to database!");
 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It is possible.

If they are `static` fields you can refer to them as `interface.variableName;` If `private` you can create getter methods like:

```
public variableType getVariableX(){
    return variableX;
}
```

and call them on an instance of that class.

For example:

```
Interface interface = new Interface();

interface.getVariableX();//<-- Assign this to a variable or do w/e operation
```

etc..

If you want more than that you need to post some code

**Update after your comment:**

For the login and password you can:

**1)** Set those fields to `static` on your interface `class`:

```
public static String login = //whatever

public static String password = //whatever
```

**2)** Inside your Connecting `class` do the following:

```
String login = interface.login;

String password = interface.password;
```

or just use them like this:

`System.out.println(interface.login);`

etc..

**NOTE:** You should also be aware of `Java` naming conventions. You should name your classes starting with a capital letter. Like `Connecting` etc.
Hope this helps

Comment: I've got public static String datalogin = log.getText(); in the Interface.java and String login = Interface.datalog; in the Connectiong, but there is error: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field Interface.datalog

Comment: Ehm.. your field in the Interface is called `datalogin` but you are calling a field called `datalog` ?

Comment: Corrected, but in 'Interface.java ' I've got error 'Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field log'

Comment: Well the error is self explanatory. Your `log` object is an instance of a class and you are calling the `getText()` method upon it. hence, non-static. Either make the `getText()` method static as well and call it like `datalogin = ClassName.getText()` or instantiate your Interface class inside your connecting class and make a getter method like i showed at the start of my answer

Answer (score 0):

Yes, like this:

```
public class Interface {
    private String foo = "bar";
    private int number = 14;

    public String getFoo() {
        return this.foo;
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return this.bar;
    }
}

public class Connecting {
    public Connecting(Interface userInterface) {
        System.out.println("Foo is " + userInterface.getFoo());
        System.out.println("Number is " + userInterface.getNumber());
    }
}
```